# Best way to implement bitwise operations for n-byte integers

Tags: fortran, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I want to implement an efficient library for bitwise operations on big integers. I've written the following function that overrides `BTEST`:

```
FUNCTION testb_i2b(n,i)
  INTEGER(I8B), DIMENSION(0:), INTENT(IN) :: n
  INTEGER(I2B), INTENT(IN) :: i
  INTEGER(I2B) :: j
  LOGICAL :: testb_i2b
  j = ISHFT(i,-6)
  IF ( j .LE. UBOUND(n,1) ) THEN
    testb_i2b = BTEST(n(j),i-ISHFT(j,6))
  ELSE
    testb_i2b = .FALSE.
  END IF
END FUNCTION testb_i2b
```

The array `n` contains the `64*(SIZE(n)-1)` bits of my big integer. Is there a more efficient way to obtain the same functionality?

Comment: Is your btest too slow? Is your aproach faster at least a bit? For which compiler?

Comment: Yes, the above implementation becomes a bottleneck in my code. I'm using ifort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether this is faster than your version, I'll leave you to test that, but it involves fewer operations and no explicit if statement so might be.  It gives the same results as your code for the few tests I've run. I've hard-wired the size of the integers in the bignum at 64 bits, you could make that a parameter if you wanted to.

```
  LOGICAL FUNCTION btest_bignum(bn,ix)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER(int64), DIMENSION(0:), INTENT(in) :: bn
    INTEGER(int16), INTENT(in) :: ix
    INTEGER :: array_ix
    array_ix = ix/64
    btest_bignum = BTEST(bn(array_ix), ix-(array_ix*64))
  END FUNCTION btest_bignum
```

Note that I've used the now-standard kind declarations `int64` and `int16`

Comment: The main difference is avoiding the IF (hence no array overflow checking, which will be faster). Multiplication and division will be compiled to shift instructions anyway.